# Reverse alphabet

Tags: python, string

I’m trying to modify a piece of text to apply the following translation:

```
before: abcdefghijqlmnopqrstuvwxyz
after:  zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

That is, each `a` becomes a `z`; each `b` becomes a `y`; each `c` becomes a `x`; and so on.

My script :

```
myInput = input("Entrer une chaine de caracteres:\n\n")
myInputSansEspace = myInput.replace(" ", "")

myInputAsciiInverse = myInputSansEspace.replace("a","z").replace("b","y").replace("c","x").replace("d","w").replace("e","v").replace("f","u").replace("g","t").replace("h","s").replace("i","r").replace("j","q").replace("k","p").replace("l","o").replace("m","n").replace("n","m").replace("o","l").replace("p","k").replace("q","j").replace("r","i").replace("s","h").replace("t","g").replace("u","f").replace("v","e").replace("w","d").replace("x","c").replace("y","b").replace("z","a")

print(myInputAsciiInverse)
```

Unfortunately it doesn’t work. For example if I write:

> i am noob

The return should be be:

> rznmlly

Because `i` gets replaced by `r`; `a` by `z`; `m` by `n`; etc.

The result I get is:

> boonmai

Comment: You needn't run the reverse on the later part of the alphabet. It's already reversed. Although it certainly more sensible to use `reverse` or `reversed`.

Comment: So all empty spaces need to be removed?

Comment: After your edit the question **totally changed**! Your addition asks about something completely different!

Answer (score 10):

Your approach has side effects, so does not do what you want.
Take your first replace:

```
'a...z'.replace('a', 'z') == 'z...z'
```

Now consider the last replace:

```
'z...z'.replace('z', 'a') == 'a...a'
```

Hence ending up with only half the alphabet.

You can simply replace all the `replace`s with `reverse` or slicing:

```
'abc..xyz'.reverse() == 'zyx..cba'
'abc..xyz'[::-1] == 'zyx..cba'
```

If you are trying to translate as a means of a cypher then you can use `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`, e.g.:

```
>>> alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> trans = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[::-1], ' ')
>>> noob = 'I am noob'
>>> noob.lower().translate(trans)
'rznmlly'
```

Note: `alphabet` is equivalent to `string.ascii_lowercase`

The above is largely equivalent to:

```
>>> import string
>>> trans_table = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase[::-1]))
>>> ''.join(trans_table.get(c, c) for c in noob.lower() if c not in ' ')
'rznmlly'
```

Comment: Thank you for your return. I did not explain my question well.

For example if i write :

    I am noob

The return need to be like this :

    rznmlly

(replace i by r) (replace a by z) (replace m by n) etc

Actually the return is :

    boonmai

 adrien

Comment: The alphabet is missing the character 'w'.

Comment: Thanks fixed... that is why I use `string.ascii_lowercase` :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a functional way to accomplish the replacement:

```
s = "I am noob"

import string   
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

# construct a dictionary mapping from a letter to its dual opposite starting from the end
# of the alphabet table
rep_dict = dict(zip(letters, letters[::-1]))

# use the dictionary to replace the letters
''.join(map(rep_dict.get, s.replace(" ", "").lower()))
# 'rznmlly'
```

---

The problem with your code is that you are doing `replace('a', 'z')....replace('z', 'a')` so all the previously replaced characters get replaced back.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean `index` it. I would call this slicing.

Comment: @AChampion Yeah, seems to be more appropriate to call it slicing here if you say [index is one element and slice is multiple elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's slice to reverse a string:

```
>>> my_string = "abcdefghijqlmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> my_reversed_string = my_string[::-1]
>>> my_reversed_string
'zyxwvutsrqponmlqjihgfedcba'
```

Edit: OK so the question is how to translate a string using a reversed alphabet. With this kind of problem the first that comes to my mind is building a dictionary to do the translating:

```
>>> alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> reversed_alphabet = alphabet[::-1] # zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(alphabet, reversed_alphabet))
>>> my_str = "i am noob"
>>> translated_str = ''.join(my_dict[c] for c in my_str.replace(' ', ''))
>>> translated_sentence
'rznmlly'
```

Comment: I edited the question to clarify OP’s problem. It’s not about reversing a string but rather translate a string using a reversed alphabet: replace `a` by `z`; `b` by `y`; `c` by `x`; etc.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a string function called `.reverse()`, which can be called by

```
var = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var = var.reverse()
print var


> zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedbca
```

Comment: Presumably the purpose of the code is to come up with his own version of that though - obviously you'd probably just use the built-in one for production code though.

Comment: In that case you can do a recursive function where you `return var[-1] + reverse(var[:-1])` with a base case for when `len(var) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 22 11:46:50 2020

@author: Tumbu John
An encryption program "REVERSE ALPHABET"
"""
```

Dictionary containing the value(new form each letter will be converted to)

```
code = {"a":"z", "b":"y", "c":"x" ,"d":"w" ,"e":"v", "f":"u", "g":"t", "h":"s", "i":"r","j":"q","k":"p","l":"o", "m":"n", "n":"m", "o":"l", "p":"k", "q":"j", "r":"i", "s":"h", "t":"g", "u":"f", "v":"e", "w":"d","x":"c", "y":"b", "z":"a"," ":" "}

plainText = input("Enter text to be encrypted: ")
plainText = plainText.lower() #Converts the input to lowecase letters for better management and error free program since python is case sensitive
encryptedText = ""
```

For loop to check for every character of the input to be converted to their respective values (encrypted text)

```
 for c in plainText:
```

This block is added to leave non-alpha in message prevent errors for input not in dict

```
if c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ":#checks if each character of plainText exist in 26 letters of alphabet
    encryptedText += code[c]
else: #if a character doesn't exist in the dictionary, do nothing to it
    encryptedText+=c
```

Encrypted text gets printed

```
print("This is the encrypted text: ",encryptedText)
```

OUTPUT

```
>>> enter text to be encrypted: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>>> this is the encrypted text: zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedbca
```

See a picture of this program : [image: See a picture of this program]

## Tumbu Nkeng John | Tumbu John | Reverse Alphabet | Reverse alphabet encryption program | Encryption program in python | Python

Answer (score 0):

```
# p[10:36] -> alphabet(lowercase)
# p[35:9:-1] -> reverse alphabet
# p[:10]+p[36:62]+p[62:] -> Remove uppercase, numbers and special characters 

import string
p = string.printable
k = [(x,y) for x in p[10:36] for y in p[35:9:-1]][0::27]
def solution(x):
    r = []
    for i in x:
        for k1,k2 in k:
            if i in p[:10]+p[36:62]+p[62:]:
                pass
            elif i == k1:
                r.append(k2)
    print(''.join(r))
    
    solution("yeah! i can't believe lance lost his job at the colony!!")
```

output:

```
"bvzs! r xzm'g yvorvev ozmxv olhg srh qly zg gsv xlolmb!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code reverses the lowercase characters by ignoring the uppercase and other characters:

```py
def solution(x): 
    i=0
    m=""
    while(i<len(x)):
        if(ord(x[i])<97 or ord(x[i])>122):
            m=m+(m.join(x[i]))  
        else:
            if(ord(x[i])<123):
                m=m+(m.join(chr(((ord(x[i])+(2*(109-ord(x[i]))+1))))))
        i=i+1 
    print(m)
```

If you run this code with `solution("@Tsrh rh vmxibkg!vw g-.vcg")`, then you will get:

```
@This is encrypt!ed t-.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks similar to Atbash which can be solved using arithmetic on the ASCII characters present within a string and using a conditional for adjusting the min and max boundaries for lower and uppercase input.
e.g.

> F(x) = min + (max - x)

Where **min** and **max** are your ASCII boundaries (96 and 123 for lowercase, 64 and 91 for uppercase) and **x** is the ASCII value of the character you are 'flipping'.

> F('a')
>
> > F(97) = 96 + (123 - 97) = 122 ('z')

```
def Atbash(cipher):

output = ""
for i in range(0, len(cipher)):
    c = ord(cipher[i])
    if 96 <= c <= 123:
        c = 96 + (123-c)
    if 64 <= c <= 91:
        c = 64 + (91 - c)
    output = output + chr(c)
return output

print(Atbash("ciphEr this"))
```

print(Atbash("ciphEr this"))

> xrksVi gsrh

Answer (score -1):

```
string=' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  '
print(''.join(string[-string.index(i)-1] for i in input().lower())) 
#replacing string with reverse letters in list comprehension and joining them
```

Or

```
[print(chr(219-ord(c))if'`'<c<'{'else c,end='')for c in input().lower()]
#ord('a') + ord('z') = 219
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).