# Sort with respect to multi-level key where the order is different for each level

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, sorting

I have a collection of items with multiple attributes which are represented by tuples:

```py
items = [(a11, a12, ..., a1N), (a21, a22, ..., a2N), ...]
```

Now I want to sort these items, however the order may vary for each level (e.g. `aX1` ascending, `aX2` descending, ..., `aXN` ascending). The crux is that these attributes are not [invertible](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) (e.g. text; otherwise the `key` could be constructed as `key=lambda a: (a[0], -a[1], ..., a[N])`).

For example with 2-tuples:

```py
items = [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a')]
reverse = (True, False)  # first level descending, second level ascending

expected = [('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]
```

Other example with 3-tuples:

```py
items = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b')]
reverse = (True, False, True)

expected = [('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b')]
```

I thought about creating a pseudo-inverse, for example via [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), but obviously this has its downsides too, as one needs to keep track of all the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all items in the tuple are string characters, you can encode them into hex string where a character `c` will be set to be `format(ord(c), 'x')` if `reverse` is not `True` and `format(127 - order(c), 'x')` if `reverse` is `True`. Now that you have the encoded string of the tuple, you can perform the regular string sorting using `sorted`

```
items = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b')]
reverse = (True, False, True)

items_sorted = sorted(items, key = lambda x: "".join([format(127 - ord(x[i]), "x") if reverse[i] else format(ord(x[i]), "x") for i in range(len(x))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which applies the `reverse` as `-1` and `1` for `True` and `False` respectively, to the *ordinaled* version of each attribute - since it's likely that string attributes are more than one character. The idea was to create a `key` function that can be passed to `sorted()`.

Edit: Here's the version with `multilevel_order` applying different reversal rules (note the name change):

```py
def multilevel_order(reverse):
    multipliers = tuple(-1 if trufal else 1 for trufal in reverse)

    def key_func(item):
        return tuple(tuple(map(m.__mul__, map(ord, attr))) for attr, m in zip(item, multipliers))

    return key_func
```

Results:

```py
items = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b'),
         ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b')]
reverse = (True, False, True)
expected = [('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'),
            ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b')]

print(sorted(items, key=multilevel_order(reverse)) == expected)
# True

items = [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a')]
reverse = (True, False)  # first level descending, second level ascending
expected = [('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]

print(sorted(items, key=multilevel_order(reverse)) == expected)
# True
```

---

Original answer: I've also used slightly modified values of `items` to make the effect of `ordinaled` clearer.

```py
items = [('a', 'bb', 'ccc'), ('a', 'cc', 'bbb'), ('a', 'bb', 'bbb'),
         ('b', 'aa', 'aaa'), ('b', 'aa', 'bbb'), ('b', 'bb', 'bbb')]
reverse = (True, False, True)

multipliers = tuple(-1 if trufal else 1 for trufal in reverse)
def multi_level_key(item):
    ordinaled = (map(ord, attr) for attr in item)
    # this multiplication step could have been included above
    return tuple(tuple(map(m.__mul__, o)) for m, o in zip(multipliers, ordinaled))
```

Example output of `multi_level_key()`:

```py
[multi_level_key(item) for item in items]
# output:
[((-97,), (98, 98), (-99, -99, -99)),
 ((-97,), (99, 99), (-98, -98, -98)),
 ((-97,), (98, 98), (-98, -98, -98)),
 ((-98,), (97, 97), (-97, -97, -97)),
 ((-98,), (97, 97), (-98, -98, -98)),
 ((-98,), (98, 98), (-98, -98, -98))]
```

Using that as the `key` for `sorted()`:

```py
sorted(items, key=multi_level_key)
# output:
[('b', 'aa', 'bbb'),
 ('b', 'aa', 'aaa'),
 ('b', 'bb', 'bbb'),
 ('a', 'bb', 'ccc'),
 ('a', 'bb', 'bbb'),
 ('a', 'cc', 'bbb')]
```

Potential improvement: I moved `multipliers` out of the key function so that it's only calculated once. Ideally, that should be put in a closure to `multi_level_key()` so that it can be used with other reversal rules without needing to write a new function.

Comment: This solution gets closest to original string comparison however I fear that performance might be hurt for longer strings, since it computes the full `ord` transformation even if only a few characters are needed. Anyway I think this can be worked around by returning a custom class from the `key` function which implements the sequence protocol and computes `ord` transformations lazily as requested (using memoization). This would then make use of the short circuiting behavior also implemented by lexicographical ordering. I will experiment with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I ended up using the following implementation which uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to identify ties within already sorted levels and then recursively sorts the corresponding groups. This has the advantage that it fully relies on the builtin string comparison methods.

```py
import itertools as it
import operator as op

def sort_one_level(data, *, reverse, level=0):
    result = sorted(data, reverse=reverse[level])
    if level + 1 < len(reverse):
        result = it.chain.from_iterable(
            sort_one_level(group, reverse=reverse, level=level+1)
            for __, group in it.groupby(result, key=op.itemgetter(level))
        )
    yield from result
```

Comment: Nice one, I was trying to figure out a way to do this so it only relies on natural sorting built-in to Python and knew there would be an `itertools.chain.from_iterable` but couldn't see how that would work correctly +1. Could you add some explanation for how the groups and chains are created?

Comment: Btw, you could also add a tuple of `key` functions for `sorted()` so it would be possible to sort a list of arbitrary tuples/iterables containing any object types as long as their `key` is correct. So something like `items = [('a', 1, userobj(7)), ('b', 2, userobj(-15))]` with `reverse = (True, False, True)` and `keys = (None, None, userobj.sortkey)` would work fine.

Comment: @aneroid The individual groups are formed by those elements that could not be distinguished within the current `level`. The previously applied `sorted` sorts all levels according to current `level`'s `reverse` preference and that is fixed during the recursive calls. Actually, if two or more levels have the same `reverse` preference, one could skip over those levels without applying an additional `sorted`, so there's still room for improvement. Also the current implementation descends into groups with only one element which isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Reverse Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048510/reverse-alphabet/42048544#42048544) to invert strings.

**Code**

```
from string import printable     # all the printable characters

def tuple_sort(items, rev):
    # Create translation table for printable characters
    trans = str.maketrans(printable, printable[::-1], ' ') 

    # key function forms list with inverted tuple items based upon rev
    return sorted(items, key = lambda item: [s.translate(trans) if flag else s for s, flag in zip(item, rev)])
```

**Test**

```
items = [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a')]
reverse = (True, False) 
tuple_sort(items, reverse)
# Result: [('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]
```